# Simulate a click on Dropdown Hiden list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to simulate a click on a dropdown list element, so first click drop show the list then select third option

i used many js fonction exemple : `document.querySelectorAll('#selectDomain > option:nth-child(2)')[0].click();`

But no one work

here is the source code :

```
<div class="row" data-select2-id="6">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
                        <select id="selectDomain" name="domain" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-live-search="true" data-select2-id="selectDomain" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                                                <option value="actu-xxo.xxu" data-select2-id="2">
                                    actu-xxo.xx - 185.246.44.131 - IP Personnalisée
                                </option>
                                                                <option value="actu-xxo.xx" data-select2-id="11">
                                    actu-xxo.xx - 106.234.167.241 - IP Personnalisée
                                </option>
                                                                <option value="actu-xxo.xxu" data-select2-id="12">
                                    actu-xxo.xx - 76.40.10.137 - IP Personnalisée
                                </option>
                                                                <option value="bsededket-news.x" data-select2-id="13">
                                    bsededket-news.xx - 76.40.10.97 - IP Personnalisée
                                </option>
                                                                                                                            </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: 695px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-selectDomain-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-selectDomain-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="
                                    actu-xxo.xx - 186.246.44.131 - IP Personnalisée
                                ">
                                    actu-xxo.xx - 165.246.44.131 - IP Personnalisée
                                </span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some jquery, not sure how to do this in normal javascript

this will select the 2nd child **(nth-child)** and then trigger the change event

```js
$('#selectDomain').find('option:nth-child(2)').prop('selected',true).trigger('change');
```

get [jquery here](https://releases.jquery.com/)

test via [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6g1czfeb/)

Comment: yes of course :)